# Getting error in stored procedure for checkUser for login

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I just need to build login form with asp.net C# for checkuser permission login

Here's my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUser 
(
  @username as nvarchar(50),
  @PWD as nvarchar(20),
  @level as int
)
AS 
BEGIN   
    --SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    --interfering with SELECT statements.   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Insert statements for procedure here  
    declare num as int  
    @num = 1    

    SELECT * 
    FROM USERLOGIN 
    WHERE USERNAME = @username 
      AND PWD = @PWD 
      AND level = @num 
END 
GO
```

And here's my C# code:

```
con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("CheckUser", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("USERNAME", txtusername.Text);
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("PWD", txtpwd.Text);
com.Parameters.Add(p1);
com.Parameters.Add(p2);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
if (rd.HasRows)
{
     rd.Read();
     Label4.Text = "Login successful.";
}
else
{
     Label4.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
}
```

I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@num

Comment: So what's the issue with your code?

Comment: in sql Must declare the scalar variable "@num

Comment: ***Please*** tell us you're ***not really*** storing user's passwords in ***clear text*** in your database!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as

```
Declare @num int 

Set @num =1  

SELECT * FROM USERLOGIN 
WHERE USERNAME=@username AND PWD=@PWD 
AND level = @num
```

if you are using SQL server below 2008

or like

```
Declare @num int=1

SELECT * FROM USERLOGIN 
WHERE USERNAME=@username AND PWD=@PWD 
AND level = @num
```

for SQL Server 2008 and above

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code snippet. From what you posted it *looks* like this is commented out:

```
declare num as int  @num = 1
```

i.e. it's on the same line as a comment. Can you confirm?

**IN FUTURE POST THE ERROR MESSAGE FIRST**

Comment: yes this line have error declare num as int  @num = 1

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to add to your code. The line is commented as [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28757411/1991504) suggested.

```
declare @num int
set @num =1
```

Comment: still error Massage is Incorrect syntax near '@num'.  and Must declare the scalar variable "@num".